# $\log_2 13$ is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logarithms, alternative-proof, rationality-testing

Is it true that $\log_2 13$ is irrational?

Let $x=\log_2 13\implies 2^x=13$.

So, it will be an irrational number, if not,$$x=\frac p q$$

and $$2^{\frac p q}=13$$

$$\implies 2^p=13^{q}$$

Since, $13$ is a prime number, $2^p$ divides $13^q$.

So, $2$ divides $13$, which is absurd.

Is this reason worthy? Can you give some other proofs for this?

Comment: That's a nice and elegant proof. You can extend it to
$$\log_a b \notin \mathbb Q \qquad \forall a,b\in\mathbb N\text{ s.t. } \gcd(a,b) = 1$$

Comment: Thank you.. Is there any other proofs???

Comment: I don't immediately see how else to tackle the problem, since $2^x = 13$ is an exponential function, so solving it would resort to $\log$ of some basis, but since we want to prove a property of $\log$, that's not going to help us much. Maybe you can reduce it to some other $\log_a b \notin\mathbb Q$ statement this way.

Comment: You could use [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), but it's not really necessary to resort to such heavy artillery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are done in your solution at the step where you concluded that $2^p = 13^q$. You only need to quote Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic after that step.